# osx - Transform unplugged screen to space

Tags: macos, window, osx-yosemite, osx-spaces

When I unplug my 2 screens from my MacBook Pro, I would like them to become 2 new spaces (or virtual desktops). Currently, I get all the windows from the unplugged screens on my primary space.

If there is a solution that works both ways, ie. transferring the spaces to monitors as I reconnect them, that would be even better.

Right now I always have to manually delete the 2 other spaces when I’m at the office, and manually recreate them and rearrange the windows when I'm away (without the 2 additional screens). It's quite annoying.

Is it possible or is there any app/AppleScript code that can do that?
I'm on Yosemite.

Comment: Right now I have a -1 on my question, not sure why... I would love to have a feedback on how improve it if my issue isn't well asked.

Comment: I revised your question a bit, please check if I accidentally changed the meaning from what you want. I think it’s an interesting question, too. ;)

Comment: @DanielB, Thanks a lot for your review! Yeah my English is a bit limited so it's sometimes hard for me to well explain my thoughts.

Comment: See if one of the answers here help: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66155/tool-to-remember-window-positions-when-i-plug-in-unplug-an-external-display

Comment: @cullub Thanks for your comment! These answers seems to address the positioning of the windows, and answer a part of my question here. Probably this week I will try to play with that and see if I can complete it with an AppleScript to manage the spaces on a plug/unplug screen event. In all cases I'll give some feedback here.